# Getting FileNotFoundException in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I want to create bean using BeanFactory, but I am getting an exeception: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: \\WEB-INF\businesscaliber-servlet.xml`.

```
Resource res = new FileSystemResource("//WEB-INF//businesscaliber-servlet.xml");
BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(res);
if (factory != null && beanId != null) {
    obj = factory.getBean(beanId);
}
```

he its working using this

ApplicationContext ctx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:/WEB-INF/businesscaliber-servlet.xml");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to specify an absolute path and not a Web application relative path to [`FileSystemResource`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/FileSystemResource.html).

Try using [`ServletContextResource`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/ServletContextResource.html) instead.

> [`Resource`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html) implementation for
>   [`ServletContext`](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html?is-external=true) resources,
>   interpreting relative paths within the
>   web application root directory.

The only issue is you need the [`ServletContext`](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html?is-external=true) so:

```
ServletContext servletContext = ...
Resource res = new ServletContextResource(servletContext,
  "/WEB-INF/businesscaliber-servlet.xml");
BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(res);
if (factory != null && beanId != null) {
    obj = factory.getBean(beanId);
}
```

It's worth noting that ideally you would retrieve this from an [`ApplicationContext`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html). From [4.4 Resource Loader](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-resourceloader) of the [Spring Reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/):

> ```
> Resource template = ctx.getResource("some/resource/path/myTemplate.txt);
> ```
>
> What would be returned would be a
>   `ClassPathResource`; if the same
>   method was executed against a
>   `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext`
>   instance, you'd get back a
>   `FileSystemResource`. For a
>   `WebApplicationContext`, you'd get
>   back a `ServletContextResource`, and
>   so on.
>
> As such, you can load resources in a
>   fashion appropriate to the particular
>   application context.

So this is the preferred method of retrieving resources.

Alternatively since `/WEB-INF/` is technically in the classpath you can use the `classpath:` prefix (as per your comment) or use [`ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.html) (which will automatically return classpath resources).

Also theres no need to put double forward slashes in. Not sure why you're doing this. Perhaps a holdover from double backslashes, which are necessary?

Comment: I am able to find out the solution using this 

ApplicationContext ctx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:/WEB-INF/businesscaliber-servlet.xml");