# Spring MVC Read and Parse a file in

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring and I'm just trying to open a simple text file and parse it so I can create some POJOs. My problem is I can't get Spring to find the txt file.

I've tried putting the file all over the place and right now I've put it in

/myAop/src/main/resources/myFile.txt

and I'm referencing it in a file called

com.myApp.pojo.Team.java

using code like this:

```
FileSystemResource resource = new FileSystemResource("/myApp/src/main/resources/myFile.txt");
File f =resource.getFile();
```

However, I'm not having any luck.

I've also tried several other locations.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: See if this helps you.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076198/getting-filenotfoundexception-in-spring

Comment: ok, that makes sense but how do i get a servlet context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I wound up doing was putting the file in base directory with the POM.xml file and then i could get to it just by using the name and not by having to use any kind of path. I'm sure there are better ways but for the time being I just needed to move on.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify file name only as **src/main/resource** is already in classpath.
Try this:

```
FileSystemResource resource = new FileSystemResource("myFile.txt");
File f =resource.getFile();
```

Try
New Xmlclasspathresource() .

Comment: That didn't work even though my txt file is there under src/main/resources. Do i need to add the file to one of the spring xml configuration files?

Answer (score 2):

Try anothe path
FileSystemResource resource = new FileSystemResource("/main/resources/myFile.txt");

Actually the file from resources is placed under classes.

Answer (score 2):

Try using absolute path

```
FileSystemResource resource = new FileSystemResource("file:C:/test/workspace/src/myApp/src/main/resources/myFile.txt");
```

You may use classpath as well, but the file should be in the classpath.

```
FileSystemResource resource = new FileSystemResource("classpath:myApp/src/main/resources/myFile.txt");
```