# Read config file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, path, config, relative-path

I'm starting to write some JavaEE code and I would like to know how to initialize variables reading their values from a file. I have this structure on my disk:

```
webProject
 |
 |-- src
 |    |-- java
 |         |-- example.java
 |
 |-- web
      |-- WEB-INF
           |-- config.properties
```

So, if I want to refer from example.java to config.properties... how can I do it? I have tryied using

```
"../../../web/WEB-INF/config.properties"
```

as fileInputStream, but it didn't work because it couldn't find the path.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Just a file not found error? Invalid path? Does it work if you drop the config file in your project folder and reference it from there?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076198/getting-filenotfoundexception-in-spring) answer

Comment: @coinbird java.io.FileNotFoundException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `servlet`, you can use [`ServletContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) the to get access to the configuration file using [`getResourceAsStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) , like this

```
InputStream inputStream = this.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/config.properties");
```

Comment: But I don't want to read it from a servlet. I want to read it outside servlets, in a non-servlet-java-file.

Comment: You must have access to `ServletContext`, what is the type of that "non-servlet-java-file"?

Comment: Also, is this a configuration file that you expect to edit in the application runtime?

Comment: A simple java file (example.java in the tree I "draw" before).

Comment: I want to edit this configuration file in the future with the application running. I don't want to write the values inside the code.

Comment: What application server are you using?

Comment: I'm using tomcat